# How can I sort my model output in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm quite new in the development with django and I hope someone can help me.
I have two main models in one view and in one template.
Each one of my "main" models has its own "sub" model (with a foreign key).
My output is fine and it works so far.

My problem is, I would like to sort the sub model of my second main model by name. Is this possible, or what do I need to change this?

In my example, I want to sort *'occupant.last_name'* by name.

I have a picture what it looks like right now: [occupant.last_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCyOT.png)

My **models.py**

```
class Management[...]
class Employee[...]

class Houses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Occupant(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(Houses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

My **views.py**

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'all_management_list'
    template_name = 'blackboard/index.html'
    queryset = Management.objects.order_by('order_number')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Houses'] = Houses.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

My **template.html**

```
{% for houses in Houses %}
<h3>{{ houses.name }}</h3>
<table><tbody>
    {% for occupant in houses.occupant_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ occupant.last_name }}, {{ occupant.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ occupant.room }}</td>
    </tr>
[...]
```

Thank you so much for helping and sorry for my bad english. :)

With best regards

borsTiHD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can sort in queryset by order_by()

order make the default order in model by last_name by adding this under class Meta

```
class Occupant(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(Houses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.first_name
    class Meta:
       ordering = ('last_name',)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. :) I also found another solution ( {% for occupant in houses.occupant_set.all|dictsort:"last_name" %} ). But I think I will prefer yours. :D

Comment: Another reason to use your solution. Thank you so much. :D And sorry, I can't upvote your answer. :/

Comment: if u need to use your solution u need to use select_related() , you can mark it as Right Answer :)

Comment: In 1 minute... you answerd to quickly. :)

Comment: :D yes , happy to help other :) with Django and other technology